# ¿Cómo eliminar o inhabilitar el botón de cerrar de un Toplevel()?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo un programa en python3 usando tkinter que he modularizado por clases. En el siguiente código el constructor recibe como parámetro un `Toplevel()` y después en el método `corregir()` creo un segundo `Toplevel()`. En este segundo `Toplevel()` incluyo un botón que llama al método `siguiente()`. Pues el caso es que, *el botón de cerrar ventana que tienen todas las ventanas por defecto*, me gustaría que también llamara al método `siguiente()` o en su defecto poder eliminarlo o inhabilitarlo.

Aquí el código:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import io
from Conexion import BBDD

class ventana_imagenes:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.mi_BBDD = BBDD()
        self.master = master        
        self.a = tk.StringVar()
        self.b = tk.StringVar()
        self.c = tk.StringVar()
        self.d = tk.StringVar()
        self.v_op = tk.IntVar() 
        self.crear_pregunta(master) 



    def crear_pregunta(self, master):

        self.num = tuple(random.sample(range(1,5),4))
        self.mezcla = tuple(random.sample(range(0,4),4)) 

        self.relacion = {self.mezcla[0]:self.num[0], self.mezcla[1]:self.num[1], self.mezcla[2]:self.num[2], self.mezcla[3]:self.num[3]}
        self.rela = dict(zip(self.num, self.mezcla))
        self.rc = self.num[0] # Respuesta Correcta

        size = (500, 500) # Tamaño máximo de escalado

        foto_importada = self.mi_BBDD.foto(self.rc) # Recupero el objeto de tipo io.BytesIO que contiene la foto
        foto_importada.thumbnail(size) # Escalamos la imagen.
        pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(foto_importada) # Convierto la foto a un formato legible por tkinter


        self.a.set(self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[0]))
        self.b.set(self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[1]))
        self.c.set(self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[2]))
        self.d.set(self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.relacion[3]))

        # ------------------- CREANDO WIDGETS --------------------
        self.imagen = tk.Label(master, image=pic, background="red")
        self.imagen.pic = pic # necesario para que muestre la imagen. También existe el atributo Label.image
        self.opI = tk.Radiobutton(master, textvariable=self.a, variable=self.v_op, value=0)
        self.opII = tk.Radiobutton(master, textvariable=self.b, variable=self.v_op, value=1) 
        self.opIII = tk.Radiobutton(master, textvariable=self.c, variable=self.v_op, value=2)
        self.opIV = tk.Radiobutton(master, textvariable=self.d, variable=self.v_op, value=3) 
        self.b_corregir = tk.Button(master, text='corregir', command=lambda:self.corregir())
        self.b_corregir.focus_set()

        # --------------- GRID --------------------------
        self.imagen.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.opI.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.opII.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.opIII.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.opIV.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.b_corregir.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e")

    def corregir(self):
        self.informe = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.informe.transient(self.master) # quita los botones de maximizar y minimizar.

        self.informe.geometry("260x175+200+150")
        self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.siguiente()) # ESTA ES LA LÍNEA QUE da problemas.
        self.corrigiendo(self.informe)
        self.b_corregir.grid_remove()


    def siguiente(self):

        self.informe.destroy() # O ESTA ... HAY QUE VERLO.
        self.crear_pregunta(self.master)
        self.b_corregir.grid()

    def pasar(self):pass


    def corrigiendo(self, contenedor):

        if self.v_op.get() == self.rela[self.rc]:
            #--------------------------------WIDGETS-------------------------
            cartel = tk.Label(contenedor)
            termino = tk.Label(contenedor)
            correccion = tk.Label(contenedor, wraplength=200) #wraplength establece el ancho de la línea.
            boton = tk.Button(contenedor)
            #--------------------------------CONFIG WIDGETS-------------------------
            cartel.config(text="correcto", bg="black", fg="green", font=('consola', 24))            
            termino.config(text=self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.num[0]))           
            correccion.config(text=self.mi_BBDD.definicion(self.num[0]))            
            boton.config(text="siguiente", command=lambda:self.siguiente())
            boton.focus_set() # poner el foco del teclado en el widget
            #--------------------------GRID-----------------------
            cartel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
            termino.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
            correccion.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
            boton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
        else:
            #--------------------------------WIDGETS-------------------------
            cartel = tk.Label(contenedor)
            termino = tk.Label(contenedor)
            correccion = tk.Label(contenedor, wraplength=200)
            boton = tk.Button(contenedor)
            #--------------------------------CONFIG WIDGETS-------------------------
            cartel.config(text="incorrecto", bg="black", fg="red", font=('consola', 24))            
            texto = "La respuesta correcta era:\n" + self.mi_BBDD.nombre(self.num[0]) + "\n"            
            termino.config(text=texto)          
            correccion.config(text=self.mi_BBDD.definicion(self.num[0]))            
            boton.config(text="siguiente", command=lambda:self.siguiente())
            boton.focus_set()
            #--------------------------GRID-----------------------
            cartel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
            termino.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
            correccion.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
            boton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='e')
```

el anterior código me genera este error:

```
    self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.siguiente()) # ESTA ES LA LÍNEA QUE DA PROBLEMAS.
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2188, in wm_protocol
    return self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel.!toplevel
```

Sé que tiene que haber algún tipo de redundancia o incongruencia en los métodos `corregir()` y/o `siguiente()` pero no termino de verla.

También he intentado inhabilitar dicho botón haciendo esto: `self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.pasar())`
pero no funciona.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda porque por más que busco no encuentro solución a mi problema.

Comment: Hola, en principio el error que veo es que le pasas el retorno del método (`None` en ambos casos) y no una referencia al mismo, debe ser : `self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.siguiente)` o `self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.pasar)` observa que es `self.siguiente / self.pasar` no `self.siguiente() / self.pasar()`  (con los paréntesis) que sería llamar al método y asignar al evento su retorno en vez del método en si mismo...

Comment: Pequeño detalle que parece de principiante, pero que no conocía... Pensaba que a un método siempre.se le llamaba con los paréntesis, retornara algo o no. Muy agradecido como siempre! Siempre respondes tu @FJSevilla eres mi ángel de la guarda friki ;P muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, resulta ser que soy más principiante de lo que creía.

Como bien me ha ilustrado @FJSevilla cuando llamamos a un método con los paréntesis, por ejemplo `self.siguiente()`, estamos llamando al retorno del método, (que en este caso no devuelve nada, de ahí el error) Si queremos llamar al método en si mismo hay que omitir los paréntesis, por seguir con el mismo ejemplo: `self.siguiente`, el problema concreto de esta pregunta se encuentra en la línea `self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.siguienteI())` que debería ser así: `self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.siguiente)`

Comment: también he comprobado que se puede hacer así: `self.informe.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda:self.siguiente())`